# AJAX/JavaScript search performance better than Java/Oracle

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, oracle, performance

I work with a very large, enterprise application written in Java which queries an Oracle SQL database. We use JavaScript on the front end, and are always looking for ways to improve upon the performance of the application with increased use.

The issue we're having right now is that we are sending a query, via Java, that results in 39,000 records. This is putting a significant load on the server and causes the browser to hang. I should mention that the data is relatively static (only changes about once a year) and we could use an xml map or something similar (flat file) since we know the exact results that will be returned each time.

The query, however, is still taking 1.5 - 2 minutes to load, which is unacceptable. I wanted to see if there were any suggestions as to how this scenario can be optimized, especially if it can be done any quicker with JavaScript (or jQuery) and using AJAX for the db connection. Or, are we going about this problem all wrong?

Comment: Usually this depends upon your sql query from which you're retrieving the data. Have you tried to optimize your query ?

Comment: If the results do not change, why not cache them in your java tier?

Comment: Sounds to me you just dealing with bandwidth (on several levels). 39K records will be XX bytes of data, with a transfer rate of Y. Server side paging seems to be a common implementation to prevent this.

Comment: I would suggest to use cache, database data may be loaded into a cache and made available to different applications. Thus, Coherence caches reduce load on the database and provide faster access to database data. For more info you can search 'Oracle Coherence' in Google.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments -- they are all very helpful. @Sharpedge yes, we've optimized the query as much as we can.

Comment: @BrettOkken The problem with the cache on the java tier is it can only be there temporarily. The first time it loads it takes a long time, but is snappier after that. Then you multiply it by number of users and you quickly get an Out Of Memory error.

Comment: Again, all good comments -- am I barking up the wrong tree to think that AJAX can help me?

Comment: Probably. AJAX is asynchronous so may help you get around locking issues on the front end whilst you are waiting for results to be returned, but you will still be waiting 1.5 - 2 minutes before you actually get to see the data.

Comment: If you don't need to see all of this data at once then you could use a REF CURSOR strategy to chunk up the data (along with some pagination perhaps)? As for taking your data outside of the database, you could potentially use a document based solution (no SQL) which you update fairly infrequently. Should be much faster.

Comment: Also, if your query is just inherently slow and you are struggling to tune it, then you could also consider a materialized view approach in order to pre-populate your query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to determine if the slowness is due to:

1. the query executing in the database
2. the network is slow returning 39k records
3. the javascript working with the 39k records after the ajax is complete

If you can run the query in sqlplus or toad, this will eliminate the web-tier and network all together.  If this is slow, then tune the query by checking indexes.

If after adding the appropriate indexes, the query is still slow, then you could prebuild the query's results and store the results in a table or you could create a materialized view.

Once you have the query performing well from sqlplus, then add the network back into the equation. Run it from your web browser and see what overhead is being added.

If it is still slow, then you need to determine if the problem is the act of ajaxing the data or if the slowness occurs after the page does something with the data (ie. populating a data grid via javascript).

If the slowness is because the browser is waiting for the data, then you want to make sure it's only ever fetched once.  You can do this by setting the cache headers in the ajax request to cache the result for 1 year. Or you can store the results in `localstorage`.

If the slowness is due to the browser working with the 39k rows (ie. moving the data into a data grid), then you have a few options.

1. find a better approach or library
2. use pagination

You may find performance issues from each of these areas.  Most likely the query just needs to be tuned and by adding indexes or pre-querying the data and storing it will solve the problem.

Another thing to consider is if you really need 39k rows at one time. If you can, paginate at the db level so you're returning 100 rows per page.